# Print an address based on an format in XML

Tags: php, xml

I have a database table with three columns: street name, house number (nullable) and city.

I want to print the address using is format:

**Correct:** "Wall Street, 11 - New York"

**Correct (house number null):** "Wall Street - New York"

**Wrong (house number null):** "Wall Street,  - New York"

I don't want to use an if/else statement because I have some different formats based on the country, so I thought about XML.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have different formats based on the country, you should use the `sprintf` function, and give as the first parameter the format you want and then the rest of parameters.
Example:

```
$format = '%1$s %2$s - %3$s';
echo sprintf($format, $house, ($number ?  ', '.$number. : ''), $city);
```

Comment: I appreciate the possibility to order the elements, but sometimes there isn't the comma, for example: "11 Wall Street - New York"

Comment: You can define different formats, with comma or without it and all the time to provide the same number of parameters. For example you can skip parameter 2 and use only '%1$s  - %3$s'

Answer (score 0):

you can try to make it generic by having something like the following:

```
echo $street . ' ' . $number ? ',' . $number : '' . $city ? ' - ' . $city : '';
```